# Exchanging Data and Instructions Between Two Raspberry Pi Via Wifi

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, c

I have an assignment where I must get two raspberry pis communicating with each other wirelessly. I know that it would be easier to use an Ethernet cable, but I think that it would be more convenient for the end user if the raspberry pis were not bound together via cable.

The catch is that the communication link must be two-way, and that data (sensor input) and instructions (display results, perform calculations on Sensor inputs) must be sent both ways. Also, using Wi-Fi for the connection is preferred, and any programs (if necessary) should be in C. Of course, other kinds of wireless connections such as bluetooth and RF would be all right, but again, Wi-Fi would be the one I'd prefer (unless there is no other option).

Thank you for any suggestions that you have (especially the clear and specific ones).

Comment: This isn't a site that is going to hand out code.  You need to show what effort you have put forth first.

Comment: nobody basically cares if the network link is wired or wireless. there's plenty of C-based code on the net, showing how to open a listening socket and how to connect to it and how to write and read the data from the socket. and yeah, this question is completely irrelevant to the RasPi, it's just about writing some basic network communication routines.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to a proof of concept, where two or more machines must exchange data, may they be rPi or any wifi enabled device, I use to go the lazy way: I include a rogue wifi router in the system. For example, to see a wifi ip camera on laptop's screen, and to log alarms on rPi memory, just set up the three pieces on the router.
Any other way demands you to know deep networking principles. This rogue router do not have to be connected to Internet. I use to hide the wifi router in a corner, and let people see things magically networking...

Answer (score 0):

> I know that it would be easier to use an Ethernet cable

Configuring the network itself might be easier, but the program you have to write will be exactly the same either way, meaning, you could use either ethernet or wifi with it.  The program itself doesn't know or care which one is in use.

To explain more clearly: you should not have any code for configuring the network in your application code.  Applications attempt to make connections assuming *the system* is on a network; they do not set up the system network themselves.<sup>1</sup>

Getting the network up and running may require a separate shell script of some sort, but ideally you should be able to configure the existing services and they will take care of that for you.

> the communication link must be two-way...any programs (if necessary) should be in C

Two-way network connections are done with IP **sockets**, which come in two predominant flavours,<sup>2</sup> TCP and UDP.  TCP are the most common and arguably the most functional, that's probably what you should use (the WWW is TCP/IP based).

The GNU C Library Reference Manual has a [nice introduction to socket programming in C](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sockets.html).  Remember: you *must* use IP sockets to communicate on a real network, meaning the relevant bits are about "internet namespace" and not "local namespace", and you *probably* want TCP sockets, which are the `SOCK_STREAM` style.

And again: the C Library counts on the system to provide an up and running network that can be used to make connections.  By analogy, your web browser does not set up your internet (eth or wifi) connection for you -- that's a system administration task.  If there's a network available, the web browser is able to use it; if not, the user is informed and can do whatever is necessary.

<sup>1</sup> If you are aware of the [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Description_of_OSI_layers), ethernet vs. wifi is part of layers 1 and 2 ("physical" and "data link").  Two-way socket communication is an aspect of level 3 and above, but the kernel takes care of implementing layers 3 and 4.  5 and 6 are sort of irrelevant in this context -- what you are doing manually in C is implementing layer 7 ("application").

<sup>2</sup> There's a 3rd kind, "raw", but you don't want to use that.